# Can including an observation level random effect (OLRE) create nested random factors in a GLMM?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, glmm, nested-data, overdispersion

I have data from an observational study on insect parasitism rates from 42 sites. Some sites were sampled only once and others were sampled multiple times across different years. For each sampling event I know the total number of individuals sampled per taxonomic group and the proportion that were parasitized.

Data are organized by individual collection events (site + year sampled + taxonomic group). I am fitting a binomial GLMM (glmer) with the proportion of parasitized individuals from each sampling event as the response and 5 continuous explanatory land cover variables measured within each site. 
I am including site as a random factor to account for repeated measures and unequal sampling effort across sites.
Here is an example of the model:

```
model<-glmer(cbind(yes,no) ~ elevation + crop + water + urban + SHDI + (1|site), family = binomial, weights = n)
```

I tested for overdispersion using the following code, which indicated that the model is overdispersed:

```
overdisp_fun <- function(model) {
    ## number of variance parameters in an n-by-n variance-covariance matrix
    vpars <- function(m) {
        nrow(m) * (nrow(m) + 1)/2
    }
    model.df <- sum(sapply(VarCorr(model), vpars)) + length(fixef(model))
    rdf <- nrow(model.frame(model)) - model.df
    rp <- residuals(model, type = "pearson")
    Pearson.chisq <- sum(rp^2)
    prat <- Pearson.chisq/rdf
    pval <- pchisq(Pearson.chisq, df = rdf, lower.tail = FALSE)
    c(chisq = Pearson.chisq, ratio = prat, rdf = rdf, p = pval)
}
```

To account for the overdispersion I am considering including an observation level random effect in the model - so essentially including each collection event as a random effect.

**My question:**
Because site defines a component of collection event, should it be considered nested within collection event?

Comment: The answer is no, in the sense that you don't need to specify the nesting. You can include your observation-level random effect by adding `(1|observation)` to the model formula. This assumes that `observation` is a factor with levels that never repeat in the whole dataset, e.g. go from 1 to N where N is the number of observations ("collection events"). You don't need any nesting because its levels never repeat, so `glmer` will take care of it.